# Definition of "nonlinear" in the context of perturbation of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, perturbation-theory, non-linear-systems, post-newtonian

What exactly is the definition of a *nonlinear perturbation* when applied to a background spacetime metric?

I have seen so called "linear perturbations" which look like
$$ds^2 = -(1+2\Phi)dt^2 +a^2(1+2\Psi)dx^2.$$

I have also read about something called the [post-Newtonian formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion).

I suppose nonlinear just means taking the scalar field perturbations not to be small and include higher powers of them? If so, what form does it take? The PPN form? Or some power expansion of $\Phi,\Psi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several definitions of *nonlinear* and each can be somewhat dependent on context.  In your question, I would imagine one could say the perturbation was nonlinear if there were higher order terms altering the "shape" of the metric.  You could also argue that the perturbations were nonlinear if they made it so the metric could not be expanded in the linear sense (e.g., like the Taylor expansion shown in your equation).  Meaning, the perturbations are coupled to the background metric, not a fluctuation superposed on the background.  In other words:
$$
dt^{2} \neq \left( 1 + \delta \phi + \frac{ \delta \phi^{2} }{ 2 } + ... \right) dt^2
$$
where $\delta \phi$ are perturbations of $dt^{2}$.

Unfortunately, my answer is somewhat ambiguous because the nature of the question is ambiguous (not your fault).